# Logistic function and linear regression line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ytick={0,.5,1},
        ymax=1,
        axis y line=middle,
    ]
        \addplot%
        [
            blue,%
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-10:10,
        ]
        (x,{1/(1+exp(-x))});        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to add a linear regression line linking the beginning and the end of the logistic distribution.

Moreover, I would like to add a scatter plot at the beginning (on the x-axis) and the end of the distribution corresponding at 1.

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to add different types of plots in a single figure? How to make this regression line? How to make a scatter plot? These are all different questions, and particularly, the latter two are not uniquely answerable as there is missing specification and data.